# ListView is not appearing - Fetching Data from Server

Tags: android, android-listview

I am **trying to Retrieve data from server** and want to show that data in a ListView.

Problem: ListView is not Appearing

**OrdersActivity.java:**

```
   public class OrdersActivity extends Activity 
    { 
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "OrdersActivity";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();;
    ListView list;
    OrdersAdapter adapter;
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_orders);


        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new OrdersAdapter(this, itemsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Permission StrictMode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_orders.java:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/header_orders" />

<ListView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/listView1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/header" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
    android:divider="#b5b5b5" 
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OrdersActivity.java:**

```
public class OrdersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    TextView tName,tId,tOid ;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    String strName,strMemberID ;

    public OrdersAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
        // return (data == null) ? 0 : data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_orders, null);

        tId = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtTotalAmount);
        tName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtItemDetails);

        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item = data.get(position);

        tId.setText(item.get(strName));
        tName.setText(item.get(strMemberID));


            String url = "http://172.16.0.4/res/order_fetch.php";
            Intent intent= activity.getIntent();
            String MemberID = intent.getStringExtra("MemberID");
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sMemberID", MemberID));
            String resultServer  = getHttpPost(url,params);

            strMemberID = "";
            strName = "";


            JSONObject c;
            try {
            c = new JSONObject(resultServer);
            strMemberID = c.getString("TotalAmount");               
            strName = c.getString("ItemDetails");

            if(!strMemberID.equals(""))
            {                   
                tName.setText(strName);
                tId.setText(strMemberID);               
            }
            else
            {               
                tName.setText("-");
                tId.setText("-");
            }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return vi;

}       

        public String getHttpPost(String url,List<NameValuePair> params) {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) { // Status OK
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str.toString();
    }
}
```

**listrow_orders.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTotalAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="#a60704"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItemDetails"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:textColor="#a60704"
    android:text="Item Details Here" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtTotalAmount"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTotalAmount"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Ordered Items:"
    android:textColor="#a60704"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Total Amount"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#a60704" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where do u get ur data in array ???

Comment: try using View Holder....

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the data within the views itself when comes to customizing of ListView. Trying implementing this:

```
public class PlacesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    // private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<String> AL_id_text = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> AL_text = new ArrayList<String>();

    public PlacesListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> AL_name_time, ArrayList<String> AL_name_time1)
    {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        // mContext = c;
        this.AL_id_text = AL_name_time;
        this.AL_text = AL_name_time1;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return AL_id_text.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return AL_id_text.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView txt_maintext;
        TextView txt_mtext;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.place_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txt_maintext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_maintext);
            holder.txt_mtext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_mtext);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txt_maintext.setText(AL_id_text.get(position));
        holder.txt_mtext.setText(AL_text.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The getView() method is called by android's ListView when it is rendering the view elements on your screen, piece by piece. You shouldn't be fetching your data in your getView() method which, more often than not, will block your UI thread.

The best way to do this would be to fetch your data **beforehand**, store it in the objects you like and use them to create ListAdapter instances. This way, you wouldn't need to wait for the image fetching to complete while Android is drawing the ListView for you.

So try fetching the data using

```
 getHttpPost()
```

outside the getView method, preferably Asynchronously.

Populate your itemsList appropriately after fetching data using this method. Create your ListAdapter instance using this itemList data. Set this adapter to your listview.